# Hibernate Query, how to use like or = on where clause depend on value passed

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, where-clause, sql-like

I have the following code and query :

```
String kodeCustomer, kodeDropship, kodeSales, kodePengirim;

kodeCustomer = kodeCustomerTextField.getText().trim();
kodeDropship = kodeDropshipTextField.getText().trim();
kodeSales    = kodeSalesTextField.getText().trim();
kodePengirim = pengirimTextField.getText().trim();

... some other code ... 
      record = session.createQuery("from PenjualanTableDb where"
    + " dtanggalpenjualan >= :dawalParm"
        + " and dtanggalpenjualan < :dakhirParm"
        + " and coalesce(ckodecustomer,'') like :custParm"
        + " and coalesce(ckodedropship,'') like :dropshipParm"
        + " and coalesce(ckodesalesperson,'') like :salesParm"
        + " and coalesce(ckodepengirim,'') like :pengirimParm")
    .setParameter("dawalParm", tanggalMulaiTrx)
        .setParameter("dakhirParm", tanggalAkhirTrx)
        .setParameter("custParm", kodeCustomer + "%")
        .setParameter("dropshipParm", kodeDropship + "%")
        .setParameter("salesParm", kodeSales + "%")
        .setParameter("pengirimParm", kodePengirim + "%")
    .list();
```

how to modify the query so it can give the correct output based on user input. 
if textfield empty then the query using like, but if textfield not empty then query using =

Is there an easy way to handle that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're asking "if the text field is empty, then query on 'textField LIKE('%')". What's the point of this? Just omit the criterion.

Comment: @NotaJD 
Thanks for the comment, sorry if my question is not clear :) 

what i need is something like this : 
_a = "abc" 
_b = "" 
so i need query (select ... where a = 'abc' and b like '%')
_a = ""
_b = "" 
then query is (select ... where a like '%' and b like '%')
 
i can used if, but it takes a lot of query combination for 4 input variable. 

Thanks...

Comment: I'm not a DBA but I'd wager that some databases aren't smart enough to realize that LIKE('%') is a nop ->> but I could be completely wrong :) Have you looked into the Criteria API (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_criteria_api.htm)?

Comment: Thanks @NotaJD, i'll try to read about criteria api above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should construct the hql query (including parameters) dynamically according to the parameters present instead of using "a like%".

Comment: Thanks for the input, i search about creating dunamic hql query and found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153385/dynamically-search-query-in-hql-with-optional-parameter

i think it can solved my problem, i'll try to implement that. 

Thanks a lot for the direction....

Comment: in that case criteria can be better option

Answer (score 0):

```
record = session.createQuery("from PenjualanTableDb where"
    + " dtanggalpenjualan >= :dawalParm"
        + " and dtanggalpenjualan < :dakhirParm"
        + " and coalesce(ckodecustomer,'') like '%:custParm%'"
        + " and coalesce(ckodedropship,'') like '%:dropshipParm%'"
        + " and coalesce(ckodesalesperson,'') like '%:salesParm%'"
        + " and coalesce(ckodepengirim,'') like '%:pengirimParm%'")
    .setParameter("dawalParm", tanggalMulaiTrx)
        .setParameter("dakhirParm", tanggalAkhirTrx)
        .setParameter("custParm", kodeCustomer)
        .setParameter("dropshipParm", kodeDropship)
        .setParameter("salesParm", kodeSales)
        .setParameter("pengirimParm", kodePengirim)
    .list();
```