# JPA CriteriaBuilder conjunction criteria into a disjunction criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I need to replicate this query into **JPA CriteriaBuilder** code:

```
....
where
     article.client_id = 1 
     and article.price > 0
     and (
           article.code like '%this is statement%' 
           or article.oem_code like '%this is statement%'
           or ( 
               article.description like '%this%'
               and article.description like '%is%'
               and article.description like '%statement%'
           )    
     )
```

and here's my code:

```
...

Root<Article> article = cq.from(Article.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

predicates.add(cb.equal(article.get(Article_.clientId), filter.getClientId()));

predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(article.get(Article_.price), BigDecimal.ZERO));

String searchQuery = filter.getSearchQuery();

Predicate disjunction = cb.disjunction();

disjunction.getExpressions().add(cb.like(article.get(Article_.code), "%" + searchQuery + "%"));
disjunction.getExpressions().add(cb.like(article.get(Article_.oem_code), "%" + searchQuery + "%"));

List<Predicate> andPredicate = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

for (String str : searchQuery.split(" ")) {
   andPredicate.add(cb.like(article.get(Article_.description), "%" + str + "%"));    
}
```

Now, how can I add this `andPredicate` to my disjunction predicate? The `getExpressions().add(...)` does not take a `Predicate` as param.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So here it's what I did and seems that is working fine:

```
...  
Predicate pr1 = cb.like(article.get(Article_.code), "%" + searchQuery + "%");
Predicate pr2 = cb.like(article.get(Article_.oem_code), "%" + searchQuery + "%");
Predicate pr3 = cb.conjunction();

for (String str : busquedaSplit) {
    Predicate newPredicate = cb.like(article.get(Article_.description), "%" + str + "%");
    pr3 = cb.and(pr3, newPredicate);
}

disjunction = cb.or(pr1, pr2, pr3);

predicates.add(disjunction);
```

Comment: man, you helped me a lot... with this approach, we can mix AND and OR operators... how did you wrote the return statement? thanx

Comment: @Hinotori I returned it converted in an array like this `predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])` and that is what you need to put in your `cq.where('...');`

Comment: Thank you so much. Your idea to use conjunction/disjunction helped me a lot